# Allow one regular window in front of fullscreen window in Qt5 C++

Tags: c++, focus, qt5, fullscreen, qwidget

In my `Qt5` `C++` Widgets application I want to display two widgets as follows:

- Widget **A** should be a normal resizable window: **OK**
- Widget **B** should be a full screen window: **OK**
- Both widgets should show simultaneously, with window **A** being the only one showing on top of window **B** : **FAIL**

I tried using all sorts of combinations of the following to no avail:

```
QWidget::setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)
QWidget::showFullscreen();
QWidget::setFocus();
QWidget::raise();
```

So how can I accomlish this?

Comment: Is one the parent of the other?

Comment: No, they are separate widgets, both with parent=0 (widgets with parents are not windows).

Comment: How about making `B` the parent of `A` and setting the `Qt::Dialog` bit in `A`'s `windowFlags` property?  Will that not get you most of what you need?  Although you're probably still at the mercy of whatever window manager is active on your OS.

Comment: @G.M.: I will try that.